# Hamiltonian cycle equivalence?

Tags: hamiltonian-path

If we have an undirected graph, is the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph equivalent to finding a subset of edges S in the graph such that every vertice appears in exactly two different edges in S?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the graph is not connected?

Comment: @Magdiragdag I can see your point, but as it stands the question needs some attention before it deserves a full answer. What I have put is an attempt to get OP to think about the situation, without doing too much.